# Is my patent expiring because of no payment?

Tags: expiration

Is a payment due on this patent? 7878576. If so, how do I pay?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be is expired - you may need to petition to revive.

> AIRFLOW DEFLECTOR ASSEMBLY

Patent #7878576

Application # 12460959

Filing Date 07/27/2009 Issue Date 02/01/2011

Payment Window Status Window 7.5 Year

Status Closed
Fees Unpaid

see https://fees.uspto.gov/MaintenanceFees